# trigger other configuration and send current build status with Jenkins

Tags: triggers, automation, jenkins

In a certain Jenkins config, I wish to trigger another configuration as **post** build action.
I want to pass as one of the parameters the current build status.

IE: a string / int that represents the status (SUCCESS/FAIL/UNSTABLE).

I have 2 options to create post build triggers:

**Using the join plugin**
[image: join plug-in]

**Using the trigger parameterized build in post build actions**
[image: parameterized build]

I wish there was some kind of accessible env variable at end of run...

Have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: this question is duplicated, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381124/is-there-information-available-when-executing-jenkins-postbuild-script-about-job/43785259#43785259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for status using Groovy script in post-build step via [Groovy Post-Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) that can access Jenkins internals via [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/). The plugin provides the script with variable *manager* that can be used to access important parts of the API (see *Usage* section in the plugin documentation).

For example, this is how you can output build result to build console:

```
def result = manager.build.result
manager.listener.logger.println "And the result is: ${result}"
```

Now, you can instead use that value to create a properties file and pass that file to Parameterized Trigger post-build step (it has such an option).

One caveat: I am not sure if it is possible to arrange post-build steps to execute in a particular order to ensure that Groovy post-build step runs before the Parameterized Trigger step.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution that will answer most cases:

Use '**Trigger Parameterized Build**' plugin, and set two triggers -

1. 'Stable or unstable but not fail'
2. 'Fail'

Each of those triggers should run the same job - let's call it '**JOB_B**'.

For each of the triggers, pass whatever parameters you like, and also pass a user-defined value:

- for trigger '**1**' use: **JOB_A_STATUS=SUCCESS**
- for trigger '**2**' use: **JOB_A_STATUS=FAIL**

Now, all you need to do is test the value of **${JOB_A_STATUS}** from **JOB_B**, to see if it is set to 'SUCCESS' or 'FAIL'.

Note this solution does not distinguish between 'stable' and 'unstable', but only knows the difference between 'fail' and 'success'.

Good luck!